# Annoying, it works on jsfiddle everytime and not on my website

Tags: jquery, web, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

why is this code not working? I simply can't understand, I spent hours on this and I still can't find whats my error, It works on jsfiddle and never works with me and my website. On jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2baqv/1541/)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>My site</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// mouse-on examples
$('#mouseon-examples div').data('powertipjq', $([
    '<p><b>Here is some content</b></p>',
    '<p><a href="http://stevenbenner.com/">Maybe a link</a></p>',
    '<p><code>{ placement: \'e\', mouseOnToPopup: true }</code></p>'
    ].join('\n')));
$('#mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
    placement: 'e',
    mouseOnToPopup: true
});


</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mouseon-examples">dfgdg</div>

</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
#mouseon-examples div {
    background-color: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 40px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Please put a better question title... and also can you clarify what "does not work" mean?

Comment: Do you see console errors on your site?

Comment: You need to run your code *after* the DOM is ready.  `$(function(){ //your code });`.

Comment: I cant put the tooltip working. Only appears text with no effects.

Comment: What you mean with DOM is ready, Ive used jquery plugins some time but lately Im having issues, but the strange thing is it works mostly on jsfiddle and never on my site.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the document onLoad option enabled in your jsfiddle (edit: Actually you Do),

If so, you need to put it in your code:

```
$(function(){
$('#mouseon-examples div').data('powertipjq', $([
    '<p><b>Here is some content</b></p>',
    '<p><a href="http://stevenbenner.com/">Maybe a link</a></p>',
    '<p><code>{ placement: \'e\', mouseOnToPopup: true }</code></p>'
    ].join('\n')));
$('#mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
    placement: 'e',
    mouseOnToPopup: true
});
})
```

-EDIT-

It seems like you forgot the CSS, add this to the html `<head>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/styles/jquery.powertip.css">`

-EDIT-

the Whole code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <title>My site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/styles/jquery.powertip.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // mouse-on examples
    $(function(){
        $('#mouseon-examples div').data('powertipjq', $([
            '<p><b>Here is some content</b></p>',
            '<p><a href="http://stevenbenner.com/">Maybe a link</a></p>',
            '<p><code>{ placement: \'e\', mouseOnToPopup: true }</code></p>'
            ].join('\n')));
        $('#mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
            placement: 'e',
            mouseOnToPopup: true
        });
        })


    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    #mouseon-examples div {
        background-color: #EEE;
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="mouseon-examples">dfgdg</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Even after that it still has no effect. Plain text with no action.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mouseon-examples div').data('powertipjq', $([
        '<p><b>Here is some content</b></p>',
        '<p><a href="http://stevenbenner.com/">Maybe a link</a></p>',
        '<p><code>{ placement: \'e\', mouseOnToPopup: true }</code></p>'
        ].join('\n')));
    $('#mouseon-examples div').powerTip({
        placement: 'e',
        mouseOnToPopup: true
    });
});
```